# ds3 drawing json data from mysql

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

When I run the following code with the json code in the script it works fine. When I run it with the second set of json data drawn from a mysql database it also works but when I try to run it with the first set of data from the database I get the following error.
ReferenceError: returnX is not defined problem.php:44:7
ReferenceError: svgSelection is not defined problem.php:78:5
Where is the error? thanks for any help with this.

```
/*  var statistics = [
{"APSYear":"2015","Domain":"Reading","Level":"3","CWK":"505.51","Aus":"425.8","Vic":"439.2"},
 {"APSYear":"2015","Domain":"Reading","Level":"5","CWK":"619.55","Aus":"498.2","Vic":"507.3"},
{"APSYear":"2015","Domain":"Reading","Level":"7","CWK":"611.08","Aus":"545.9","Vic":"550.9"},
{"APSYear":"2015","Domain":"Reading","Level":"9","CWK":"620.02","Aus":"580.4","Vic":"586.8"}
];*/

d3.json("statistics.php", function(statistics) {
    statistics.forEach(function(d) {
    d.APSYear = +d.APSYear;
    d.Level = +d.Level;
    d.CWK = +d.CWK;
    d.Aus = +d.Aus;
    d.Vic = +d.Vic;
});

var svgSelection = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("transform", "translate(200,0)")
    .attr("width", 900)
    .attr("height", 600)

var rectangle = svgSelection.selectAll("rect")
    .data(statistics)
    .enter()
    .append("rect");    

var rectangleattributes = rectangle
  .attr("x", function (d){
  if (d.Level === "3") { returnX = "50";
                     } else if (d.Level === "5") { returnX = "200";
                     } else if (d.Level === "7") { returnX = "350";
                     } else if (d.Level === "9") { returnX = "500";}
                     return returnX;
                     })
  .attr("y", function (d) {
  if (d.Level === "3") { returnY = (800 - d.CWK);
                     } else if (d.Level === "5") { returnY = (800 - d.CWK);
                     } else if (d.Level === "7") { returnY = (800 - d.CWK);
                     } else if (d.Level === "9") { returnY = (800 - d.CWK);}
                     return returnY;
                     })
  .attr("width", 50)
  .attr("height", function (d) {
  if (d.Level === "3") { returnHeight = d.CWK-d.Aus;
                     } else if (d.Level === "5") { returnHeight = d.CWK-d.Aus;
                     } else if (d.Level === "7") { returnHeight = d.CWK-d.Aus;
                     } else if (d.Level === "9") { returnHeight = d.CWK-d.Aus;}
                     return returnHeight;
                     })
  .style("fill", "white")
  .style("stroke", "black");
});

 /* var reading = [{"FirstName":"John","Surname":"Brown","APSYear":"2015","Level":"Year 7","READING":"643.3"},
{"FirstName":"John","Surname":"Brown","APSYear":"2013","Level":"Year 5","READING":"513.7"},
{"FirstName":"John","Surname":"Brown","APSYear":"2011","Level":"Year 3","READING":"493.5"}
];*/

   d3.json("selectdata.php?student=<?php echo $student ?>", function(reading) {
    reading.forEach(function(d) {
    d.READING = +d.READING;
   });  

//Add SVG Text Element Attributes       

var point = svgSelection.selectAll("circle")
                      .data(reading)
                      .enter()
                      .append("circle");

var circleAttributes = point
                   .attr("cx", function(d) {
                     var returnX;
                     if (d.Level === "Year 3") { returnX = "75";
                     } else if (d.Level === "Year 5") { returnX = "225";
                     } else if (d.Level === "Year 7") { returnX = "375";
                     } else if (d.Level === "Year 9") { returnX = "525";}
                     return returnX;
                   })          
                   .attr("cy", function (d) {
                   var returnY;
                   returnY = 800 - d.READING;
                   return returnY; })
                   .attr("r", 5)
                   .style("fill", "red");

var text = svgSelection.selectAll("text.value4")
                    .data(reading)
                    .enter()
                    .append("text");

//Add SVG Text Element Attributes   
var textLabels = text
  .attr("x", function (d){
  if (d.Level === "Year 3") { returnX = "105";
                     } else if (d.Level === "Year 5") { returnX = "255";
                     } else if (d.Level === "Year 7") { returnX = "405";
                     } else if (d.Level === "Year 9") { returnX = "555";}
                     return returnX;
                     })
             .attr("y", function (d) {
                var returnY;
                returnY = 800 - d.READING;
                return returnY; })
             .text( function (d) { return d.READING;})
             .attr("dy", ".35em")           // set offset y position
             .attr("text-anchor", "start") // set anchor y justification
             .attr("font-size", "10px")
             .attr("fill", "red"); 
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by first set of data and second set of data.
Could you please put up your dataset ..

Comment: I have commented out the json version of each dataset - the first is called statistics, the second reading. Both of these have been copied from what was produced by the php code to read from the mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

This code below is an Ajax call and is asynchronous lets call it code snippet1

```
d3.json("statistics.php", function(statistics) {
    statistics.forEach(function(d) {
    d.APSYear = +d.APSYear;
    d.Level = +d.Level;
    d.CWK = +d.CWK;
    d.Aus = +d.Aus;
    d.Vic = +d.Vic;
});
```

Lets call this snippet2

```
var svgSelection = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("transform", "translate(200,0)")
    .attr("width", 900)
    .attr("height", 600)

var rectangle = svgSelection.selectAll("rect")
    .data(statistics)
    .enter()
    .append("rect");
```

Just because snippet1 is async it will be executed later and snippet2 will be executed first.

So to ensure that snippet2 is executed after ajax re write your code like this:

```
d3.json("statistics.php", function(statistics) {
    statistics.forEach(function(d) {
    d.APSYear = +d.APSYear;
    d.Level = +d.Level;
    d.CWK = +d.CWK;
    d.Aus = +d.Aus;
    d.Vic = +d.Vic;
}
//now make the graph
var svgSelection = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("transform", "translate(200,0)")
    .attr("width", 900)
    .attr("height", 600)

var rectangle = svgSelection.selectAll("rect")
    .data(statistics)
    .enter()
    .append("rect");    
...your other code.
);
```

When you simply provide the json there is no Ajax thus all the code gets executed sequentially and you don't get that error.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I am still having problems with the code. The only difference that I can see in your version of the code is the closing brackets and braces. When I run it I get an error

Comment: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list . The thing that I find strange is that the code works for the reading data but not for the statistics data. Thanks for any more help that you can give me.